# Persist an entity via a bean on a JSP: NullPointerException on EntityManager

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, jpa, javabeans

I'm totally new to JSP and I tried to develop a simple program to test what I learned so far.
What I did is a JSP page that uses a Bean and tries to persist an entity with the info provided by the user. The Web app is deployed on a glassfish4 server

The entity is a simple User.java class with setters and getters (I can use it in a servlet, so there should be any issue with that).

The Bean is the following UserEJB.java class

```
@LocalBean
@Stateless
public class UserEJB implements Serializable {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName="scuoleSciPU")
    private EntityManager em; 

    public List<Request> findUsers() {
        Query query = em.createNamedQuery("findAllUsers");
        return query.getResultList();
    }

    public User createUser(User user) {
        em.persist(user); <-- here is where NullPointer is throw
        return user;
    }
}
```

The JSP page is the following page where the user is redirected after submitting a form.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<jsp:useBean id="userEjb" type="com.storassa.javaee.scuolesci.UserEJB" class="com.storassa.javaee.scuolesci.UserEJB"
        scope="session">
</jsp:useBean>
<%@ page import="com.storassa.javaee.scuolesci.User" %>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Successful registration</title>
</head>
<BODY>
<h1>You have successfully registered to this website</h1>
<% 
    User user = new User();
    user.setEmail((String)request.getParameter("email"));
    user.setName((String)request.getParameter("name"));
    user.setSurname((String)request.getParameter("surname"));
    user.setPassword((String)request.getParameter("password"));
    user.setYearOfBirth(Integer.parseInt((String)request.getParameter("yearOfBirth")));
    userEjb.createUser(user);

    session.setAttribute("logged", "true");
    session.setAttribute("name", user.getName());%>
<a href="carousel.jsp"><h3>Return to main page</h3></a>
</BODY>
</html>
```

When the JSP page is loaded, a NullPointerException is thrown (in em.persist() as described in the code above). This is the complete error stack

```
StandardWrapperValve[jsp]: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.storassa.javaee.scuolesci.UserEJB.createUser(UserEJB.java:32)
    at org.apache.jsp.registered_jsp._jspService(registered_jsp.java:73)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:111)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:411)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:473)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:377)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: where did u initialize the EntityManager?

Comment: I used injection with the @PersistenceContext annotation. I used the same mechanism to persist other objects in servlets and it perfectly works

Comment: Don't use jsp:useBean. Its old, obsolete, confusing, and undoubtedly does not work like you think it does.

Comment: And since you're using scriptlets anyway, you can always pull the bean out of the session with `session.getAttribute`: no need to jsp:useBean

Comment: I don't understand you last comment.  For the first one I took as reference a book written in 2012, where useBean is specified. Why do you say it's obsolete?

Answer (score 0):

When you use jsp:useBean, the servlet container looks for a bean with that name (or type) in the request/session/servlet contexts. If it does not find one it will instantiate one.
Your bean, even though you declared it as SessionBean is not in either of these contexts, it is in a EJB container. So, what you are referring from JSP is a simple instance of that class, not an actual EJB. As consequence, the dependency injection mechanism did not work, so EntityManager variable is null.
You should lookup for the EJB in order to get a proper EJB instance (with all DI done) or use CDI.

Comment: Could you provide me with an example for the lookup or for the CDI?